# Magento how to escape from the shipping method from the checkout page?

Tags: php, magento, plugins, checkout, magento-1.8

I have tried different options for escape the shipping method from magento default checkout page. [Blog](http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-remove-shipping-method-step-one-page-checkout-magento) but i could'nt found a work around for this, i have already asked this question in magento forum but no reply. if any one tried please give the answer its appreciated.How to remove shipping method from checkout page [Magento Forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/1033138/)

Answer (score 4):

In short, you can not skip checkout without shipping method as Magento do not save order without shipping method. If you really want to skip, you have to cheat. Assign any shipping method internally
There is multiple steps:

1. Extend `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`
2. Override `saveBillingAction` and `saveBillingShippingAction` method of `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController` and save shipping method.

   `$method = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
   $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($method);
   Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()-> setShippingMethod($method)->save();`
3. Also extend `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract` and override Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract::_getStepCodes to hide shipping steps in checkout.